# ServiceStack to expose service to multiple clients?

Tags: servicestack

Recently I made the decision to move from Xamarin.Android to native Android development.  In the previous Xamarin project I used their walkthrough to call a WCF service from Android with basicHttpBinding, primary purpose in this case to upload a DTO with an image byte array.  I'm now trying to figure the best way to do the same (or better) from Android without Xamarin.

Can ServiceStack help me expose a WCF or ASMX service such that most any client (in my case WPF/Silverlight, iOS, Android) can connect to it with the most appropriate message format (SOAP, REST, etc)?  If so please point to the best sample for quick adaptation of an existing WCF service hosted in IIS. I'm hoping to get implement quickly for a demo in one week, then circle back and spend more time learning it.

Sincere thanks
Mark